# What does this connection string mean?

Tags: sql, connection-string

```
data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
```

Specifically what does

```
AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.md
```

mean?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the connection will open *aspnetdb.mdb* on published app data dir.
This avoid you to read dir inside your web app once published.
Visual Studio does it automatically for you at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

|DataDirectory| (enclosed in pipe symbols) is a substitution string that indicates the path to the database. It eliminates the need to hard-code the full path which leads to several problems as the full path to the database could be serialized in different places. DataDirectory also makes it easy to share a project and also to deploy an application.

For example, instead of having the following connection string:

"Data Source= c:\program files\MyApp\Mydb.sdf"

Using DataDirectory, you can have the following connection string:

“Data Source = |DataDirectory|\Mydb.sdf”

To set the DataDirectory property, call the AppDomain.SetData method. If you do not set the DataDirectory property, the following default rules will be applied to access the database folder:
•   For applications that are put in a folder on the user's computer, the database folder uses the application folder.
•   For applications that are running under ClickOnce, the database folder uses the specific data folder that is created.

*i forgot to add the link so here ya go ->
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/
 *

Comment: You should have added the source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/